# Retrieving data from Streamsets Data Collector (SDC) protected by Kerberos

Tags: python-2.7, streamsets

I am trying to retrieve data from the SDC API protected by Kerberos. Initially i am posting the credentials to the SCH login page and then using the cookies generated to access the SDC rest api. However, i am not able to post the credentials. Response code is 401 and hence not able to access api.

```
dpm_auth_creds = {"userName":"", "password":"" }
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Requested-By": "SDC"}
auth_request  = requests.post("https://url:18641/sch/security/users" , data=json.dumps(dpm_auth_creds), headers=headers, verify="file.pem")
cookies = auth_request.cookies
print(auth_request.status_code)
print(auth_request.headers)
url = requests.get("https://url:18641/jobrunner/rest/v1/sdcs", cookies=cookies)
print(url.text)
```

Response code is 401: for auth_request.status_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the REST API page in Control Hub:

```
# login to Control Hub security app
curl -X POST -d '{"userName":"DPMUserID", "password": "DPMUserPassword"}' https://cloud.streamsets.com/security/public-rest/v1/authentication/login --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "X-Requested-By:SCH" -c cookie.txt

# generate auth token from security app
sessionToken=$(cat cookie.txt | grep SSO | rev | grep -o '^\S*' | rev)
echo "Generated session token : $sessionToken"

# Call SDC REST APIs using auth token
curl -X GET https://cloud.streamsets.com/security/rest/v1/currentUser --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "X-Requested-By:SCH" --header "X-SS-REST-CALL:true" --header "X-SS-User-Auth-Token:$sessionToken" -i
```

So your Python code should be more like:

```
dpm_auth_creds = {"userName":"", "password":"" }
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Requested-By": "SDC"}
auth_request  = requests.post("https://url:18641/security/public-rest/v1/authentication/login" , data=json.dumps(dpm_auth_creds), headers=headers, verify="file.pem")
cookies = auth_request.cookies
print(auth_request.status_code)
print(auth_request.headers)
# Need to pass value of SS-SSO-LOGIN cookie as X-SS-User-Auth-Token header
headers = {
  "Content-Type":"application/json",
  "X-Requested-By":"SCH",
  "X-SS-REST-CALL":"true",
  "X-SS-User-Auth-Token":auth_request.cookies['SS-SSO-LOGIN']
}
url = requests.get("https://url:18641/jobrunner/rest/v1/sdcs", headers=headers)
print(url.text)
```